# laravel 5 advance eloquent multiple selection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a table containing multiple artist. While creating an event (updating event table) I need to select artists that I want to perform at my event and need to add their ids in the event_artist (transitive) table (that contains event_id & artist_id). How shall I proceed?

Comment: Post up what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would define a [many to many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

In Artist model class:

```
public function events()
{
    $this->belongsToMany(Event::class);
}
```

In Event model class:

```
public function artists()
{
    $this->belongsToMany(Artist::class);
}
```

This assumes your pivot table is named `artist_event` (the other two table names combined in alphabetical order). Otherwise you can pass the pivot table name as the second argument to belongsToMany: `belongsToMany(Event::class, 'event_artist')`.

Then you can [attach](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-many-to-many-relationships) an artist to an event using `$event->artists()->attach($artist);`. Or detach `$event->artists()->detach($artist);`. You can also sync a collection of artists: `$event->artists()->sync($artists);`. You can also attach, detach or sync events to artists. All three methods will accept either Eloquent models or ids.